# Trying to find text next to a span using jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following code in my web page. I need to find the product name that appears after a span with class of `pn`. When I run the code below, I get empty string from `getFirstProduct` method and also an empty string from `getSecondProduct` method. However, if I use following expression then I get the correct product name: `$("#p0  span.pn")[0].nextSibling.data` or `$("#p1  span.pn")[0].nextSibling.data` but this is using JavaScript and I was wondering if there is a pure jquery solution.

A demo for this question is at this URL: [demo code](http://js.do/sun21170/77931)

**Question** : What should be the correct selector in these two methods so they return `Product 0` and `Product 1` respectively?

**Code to find product name**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='p0'>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div></div>
     <div><span class='t pn'>Product : </span>Product 0</div>
     <div></div>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div>some content</div>
    </div>
    <div id='p1'>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div></div>
     <div><span class='t pn'>Product : </span>Product 1</div>
     <div></div>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div>some content</div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="var x =  getFirstProduct(); alert(x);">Get First Product</button>
<button type="button" onclick="var x =  getSecondProduct(); alert(x);">Get Second Product</button>

<script>
function getFirstProduct() {
    return $("#p0  span.pn").next().text();
}

function getSecondProduct() {
   return $("#p1  span.pn").next().text();
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE 1**

Based on answer given and also the post whose duplicate this was marked as, I came up with following code that works perfectly.  Demo code for solution is at this URL: [solution code demo](http://js.do/sun21170/77935).

The idea is to get the parent div of span with class of `pn` and then get all types of nodes only under it i.e. one level down from parent only, which is done by `contents()` method (  and not `children()` method since children will ignore text nodes).  This would give us two elements - span and the text following the span element since these two are the only `immediate` children of parent div. The text node would be the name of Product that we are seeking.

*When seeking text nodes in jquery, it seems that `contents()` method will almost always be required.*

**Code that works**

```
<div id='p0'>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div></div>
     <div><span class='t pn'>Product : </span>Product 0</div>
     <div></div>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div>some content</div>
    </div>
    <div id='p1'>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div></div>
     <div><span class='t pn'>Product : </span>Product 1</div>
     <div></div>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div>some content</div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="var x =  getFirstProduct(); alert(x);">Get First Product</button>
<button type="button" onclick="var x =  getSecondProduct(); alert(x);">Get Second Product</button>

<script>
function getFirstProduct() {
 return $("#p0  span.pn").parent().contents().filter(function(index) { return this.nodeType === 3 ;}).text();
}

function getSecondProduct() {
   return $("#p1  span.pn").parent().contents().filter(function(index) { return this.nodeType === 3 ;}).text();
}
</script>
```

Comment: @j08691, That was a good pointer, though not easy and quick to grasp. But with some effort it's all clear now. I learnt two very important jquery concepts - `contents` and `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#out0').on('click', function(e) {

    
    getFirstProduct();
  });


  $('#out1').click(function(e) {

    
    getSecondProduct();
  });

  function getFirstProduct() {
    $("#p0 span.pn").text('');
    var txt0 = $("#p0 span.pn").parent().text();
    $('#out0').text(txt0);
  }

  function getSecondProduct() {
    $('#p1 span.pn').text('');
    var txt1 = $("#p1 span.pn").parent().text();
    $('#out1').text(txt1);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='p0'>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div></div>
  <div><span class='t pn'>Product : </span>Product 0</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div>some content</div>
</div>
<div id='p1'>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div></div>
  <div><span class='t pn'>Product : </span>Product 1</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div>some content</div>
</div>
<button id="out0">Get First Product</button>
<button id="out1">Get Second Product</button>
```

Comment: Great. That works and I tried in Edge, IE11, Chrome and FireFox.  Why is `next` not working out in my case?

Comment: The span is inside the div that has your text. So that div is actually the span's parent. So from the span you would use `.parent().next().text()` I believe. That's great that it works for you. :)

Comment: The only issue with the code you gave is that it's also getting `Product :` as part of product name. I only wanted `Product 0` or `Product 1` and not `Product : Product 0` or `Product : Product 1`.

Comment: The `Product:` text belongs to the span... I don't think that'll be a prob, wait one sec for update.

Comment: @Sunil, ok it's updated and ready for review, sir.  I'll be around if you need anymore help.

Comment: It's still prefixing the product name with `Product :`.

Comment: My bad, I thought you wanted that included because the original result was sans `product:` prefix. I think Chrome and IE Edge render differently.

Comment: No, the  original code was giving the `Product: ` prefix.

Comment: Your right, I think my expectations mentally blinded me. I'll be back with update.

Comment: @Sunil, that was harder than I thought. That's one reason I prefer JS, string methods are powerful yet simple. I learned that jQuery *flattens*  arrays when rendering strings eventListeners are removed.

Comment: No problems. I think your approach is to remove the span text and the get parent text.  I think `$("#p0 span.pn)[0].nextSibling.data` would give the first product name in a short and quick manner. May be its best to combine jquery and JavaScript, rather than do it in pure jquery.

Comment: Indeed, I have a habit to think in JS, the conveniences of jQuery eludes me at times. I'm glad you came up with a succinct solution. :)